# Vulkan: passing a "merl" file to the shader

Tags: c++, shader, vulkan

I can’t pass a “merl” file to my vertex shader as a uniform object:
`layout(set = 1, binding = 0) uniform myUniform { double brdf[4374000];  };`
I think the file is too large, it’s 32 MB, taken from:
https://cdfg.csail.mit.edu/wojciech/brdfdatabase
(obviously I copied the file into a double array)

if I write, say
`double brdf[1000];` 
the program doesn’t crash.
How do you use a merl file to implement a brdf in Vulkan?
Should I increase the buffer size?
How?

Comment: Why do you need 100 different materials to render a single object? If you really need to do that, you're probably going to have to use shader storage buffers rather than uniform buffers. You can also probably get by with 32 bit floats, rather than 64 bit floats, saving you 50% memory.

Comment: @vandench: I'm not rendering 100 different material, it's the same material that contains 4374000 doubles, they are the data regarding different theta_in, fi_in, theta_out and fi_out in any possible way

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but why are you trying to pass this in the uniform buffer? Why not just use a texture?

Comment: @user2407038: a texture is different from a merl file, I'm talking about diffuse/specular reflection for any fragment in the scene, not the emission color

Comment: Your questions seems to imply that you represent a merl file as an array of float/double, if so then a merl file is definitely representable as a texture. After all a texture is little more than an array of floats. Another commenter already suggested storage buffers, which would be a good choice for heterogenous data. In any case, you simply cannot use uniform buffers here, use a texture (for a float array) or a storage buffer (for a struct array).

Comment: @user2407038: thank you, I will study storage buffers, I can't use them. I tried to convert a texture into an array in the fragment shader, but I didn't succeed:
layout(set = 1, binding = 1) uniform sampler1D txtr;
double x = txtr[0]; // not accepted
or
layout(set = 1, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D txtr;
double x = txtr[1][1]; // not accepted
I get a compilation error in the fragment shader

Comment: If you are trying to "convert a texture to an array" then I feel like you have missed some very basic knowledge about how to write shaders. I would suggest starting by learning about the basic process of "sampling" or "loading" from a texture in a shader before trying to tackle this problem.